# GridView for UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, gridview, uiscrollview, uilabel

Can anyone help me how to create this kind of grid? Each block has label inside.

I have created a for loop to add label vertically & added as subview of `UIScrollView` earlier but it had fix size for all labels but this one has fix height for perticular row & 4/8 different type of size is there, i am guessing it can be done via sizetofit but it will not give me the desired output.

Total two type of grid view are there which i m trying to achieve using following methods:

1) `UIView`+`UILabel`
2) `UiCollectionView`

[image: Grid Sample]

[image: Grid Sample 2]

Comment: Why are you not using `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: @TarunTyagi hmm, i m thinking of it only but  how do i addd the border?

Comment: Maybe add a `borderColor` for the `UIColllectionViewCell`.

Comment: @TarunTyagi I have tried a lot but unable to it via collection view. Also first colum is static.